# How can I send messages with attachments from circuit unify?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I need to send messages with attachments to the conference, also update messages for all users with an event.

Can somebody help me?

any example please

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you specify what you have tried so far with a code example as this would also tell whether you are using the REST API or JS SDK (or Node.js SDK).

I'll assume you are using the JS SDK.

To send attachments use the [addTextItem](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/#method_addTextItem) API. As seen on that page the `attachments` attribute is a regular [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object.

An example app with file upload is available at https://github.com/circuit/circuit-sdk/blob/master/examples/js/messaging.html and running live at https://rawgit.com/circuit/circuit-sdk/master/examples/js/messaging.html.

This example is listed on our examples page at https://circuit.github.io/jssdk.html

Note that if you are referring to Node.js SDK file upload see example https://github.com/circuit/node-sdk-example

I am not clear what you mean "also update messages for all users with an event". The event raised when sending a message (with or without attachment) is [itemAdded](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#event_itemAdded).

Subscribe to it via:

```
client.addEventListener('itemAdded', evt => {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer,
i wil try with File object.

and add event
client.addEventListener('itemAdded', evt => {
    console.log(evt);
});

Comment: https://rawgit.com/circuit/circuit-sdk/master/examples/js/messaging.html

we use the example app with fileupload but i can't see the attachments just the message